# Fill array field with another array items

Tags: javascript, angular

```
tradeArray = ['ITD', 'TND', 'TRD']
trade = []

this.tradeArray.map(val => this.trade.push({
      "value": val,
      "checked": false,
}))
```

I have this snippet and I want to add one more field to `trade` array, `counter`.

For example, if I have `count = [3, 5, 2]` I want to obtain:

```
0: {value: "ITD", checked: false, counter: 3}
1: {value: "TND", checked: false, counter: 5}
2: {value: "TRD", checked: false, counter: 2}
```

I hope by this example you will understand what I want to obtain. I tried something like this:

```
count = [3, 5, 2]
this.tradeArray.map(val => this.trade.push({
  "value": val,
  "checked": false,
  "counter": this.count.map(val => val)
}))
```

but this will give me

```
0: {value: "ITD", checked: false, counter: [3, 5, 2]}
1: {value: "TND", checked: false, counter: [3, 5, 2]}
2: {value: "TRD", checked: false, counter: [3, 5, 2]}
```

How can I modify in order to obtain what I want? Thank you for your time!

Comment: From where did you get this information `countITD = 3, countTND = 5, countTRD = 2`

Comment: They are just counters, how many times `ITD`, `TRD` and `TND` appear in a list.

Comment: i guess you don't understand what the map function is for. The map function takes every value of a list and mutates it with the function. the return value will be a list with the mutated values.
What you are doing is not mapping the values but looping through them, use forEach

Comment: @Isitar you may want to avoid using the word "mutate" when the function does not actually "mutate" the original value

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca You're right, it produces a new transformed value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're sure the `count` array is in the same order as the `tradeArray`, you can use the index `.map` provides

```
count = [3, 5, 2]
this.trade = this.tradeArray.map((val, index) => {
  "value": val,
  "checked": false,
  "counter": count[index]
})
```

Comment: This answer misuses the `map` method. Use `forEach` instead

Answer (score 3):

First of all, don't use `map` just to iterate over collections. Instead, use it for what it is meant to be used: It projects a function to every item in a collection and creates a new collection (Array in your case) from the return values of the function. If you just want to iterate, use `forEach` instead.

There are multiple possible solutions, but basically what you want is some association between the "trade" in `tradeArray` and the values inside your counts. You can use index positions for that:

```
var countITD = 3, countTND = 5, countTRD = 2;

var tradeArray = ['ITD', 'TND', 'TRD']
var counts = [countITD, countTND, countTRD]

var trade = tradeArray.map((name, index) => {
  return {value: name, checked: false, counter: counts[index]};
});
// -> [{value: 'ITD', checked: false, counter: 3}, ..., {value: 'TRD', checked: false, counter: 2}]
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to match the index of `tradeArray` to same index in `count` array to get the associated value from `count`

```js
const tradeArray = ['ITD', 'TND', 'TRD'],
  count = [3, 5, 2];
  
const res = tradeArray.map((v,i)=> ({value:v, checked:false, count:count[i]}));

console.log(res)
```